# Most adequate method for obtaining data

Tags: matlab, matrix, operations

Let us suppose I do have two functions on a grid `[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y)`,

`f=f(x,y)` and `g=g(x,y)`

and I want to calculate

`sqrt(f^2+g^2)`

in two different ways:

- Expanding `f^2` and `g^2` symbolically first and then applying

  `V1=(f.^2+g.^2).^(1/2)`.
- Using `f=f(X,Y)`, `g=g(X,Y)` (this is, computing `f` and `g` on the grid first) and then applying the puntual operation over the matrices

  `V2=(f.^2+g.^2).^(1/2)`

Unfortunately, when I calculate `abs(V1-V2)`, I don't get zero in all positions.

In my case, the functions have the form

`f=f(x,y,cos(x),cos(y),cos(x)cos(y))`

and the same for `g`.

What could be the best method to calculate this operations in order to get the closest result with respect to the analytical function without changing the grid?

Comment: what is the order of magnitude of `abs(V1-V2)`? Numerical approximations are never exact.

Comment: the order of magnitude is -15 (a very small error), but still, in my problem very small variations on the data can lead to catastrophic results.

I just want to know  the explanation of this difference.

Comment: Numerical approximation is the explanation of the error. `1e-15` is machine accuracy, nothing you can do about that. The only option for getting a higher accuracy than machine epsilon is symbolic math, like your first version. That however does not produce usable numbers MATLAB can work with and is very slow.

Comment: So should I make first everything symbolic and then at the end apply the numerical approach? What if my analytical functions are huge expressions? Wouldn't it lead to more mistakes than just taking the numerical approach at first?

Comment: Without seeing your code, no idea. Usually an error of `1e-15` is significantly smaller than anything one requires, and MATLAB is a numerical program, so that's obviously the faster way.